# Sequential Creation of pods in a kubernetes StatefulSet

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, sequence, statefulset, kubernetes-statefulset

I am having difficulties with deploying my application which needs to know inside state of the cluster regarding the particular statefulset and behave accordingly.
So in my deployment.yml file, I add

```
spec:
 serviceName: "my-service"
  replicas: 3
```

Which kubernetes will create 3 pods instantly ( it will not wait until the application inside the container starts) which is not desired in my case. 
So I have a logic in the application like if its the first replica, do behavior1 if its the second (or any other than first) pick up the last ip of the spawned pod in the statefulset and then connect to it.

Below is my code

```
    String containerRingLastNodeIP = null;
    ApiClient client = null;
    Configuration.setDefaultApiClient( client );

    V1PodList list = null;
    try
    {
        client = Config.defaultClient();
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        SystemLogger.logSystemErrorMessege( e );
    }
    CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api( client );
    try
    {
        list = api
                .listNamespacedPod( "mynamespace", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                        null, null );
    }
    catch ( ApiException e )
    {
        SystemLogger.logSystemErrorMessege( e );
    }

    if ( list == null )
    {
        SystemLogger.logSystemInfoMessege( "PODS list is empty" );
    }

    List<V1Pod> containersList = list.getItems().stream()
            .filter( x -> x.getMetadata().getName().contains( CONTAINER_NAME_TAG ) ).sorted( ( o1, o2 ) -> {
                int pod1Id = Integer.parseInt( o1.getMetadata().getName().split( "-" )[1] );
                int pod2Id = Integer.parseInt( o2.getMetadata().getName().split( "-" )[1] );
                return pod1Id > pod2Id ? 1 : ( pod1Id < pod2Id ? -1 : 0 );
            } ).collect(
                    Collectors.toList() );

    String[] containerArguments;
    if ( containersList.size() == 1 )
    {
        //do logic 1
    }
    else
    {
        V1Pod recentlyInitializedContainer = containersList
                .get( containersList.size() - 2 );//remove the existing pod from the list
        containerRingLastNodeIP = recentlyInitializedContainer.getStatus().getPodIP();
        //do logic 2
    }
```

So as kubernetes do not wait until my code runs in a pod and it just starts pods, my logic fails and it does not work as expected.

The only way at the moment I see is to put replicas = 1 and scale it up manually which I don't think is good. 
scaling in the deployment time wont help as the same issue raises. Any idea of getting this done through kubernetes ?

Comment: First I would have to ask, why do you need them to start one at a time? Even waiting until all of them were up would be easier than trying to do one at a time logic.

Comment: Its basically to create a JADE containers ring inside a kuberenetes cluser. So 1st one should be a main container, and the others are backup-maincontainers who connected to the recent started container.

Comment: Do they have to be created serially, e.g. 1-2-3, or does one have to start, then all the others can start in any order, e.g. 1-(2 or 3)-(2 or 3)

Comment: 1-(2 or 3) idea is correct. But its not 2 or 3 it is 2. i mean I only have 2 types of behavoours. So 1st one is a main container. All others are backup containers. But each backup container should have a prior knowledge of the last node of the container ring to connect. Knowledge in the sense the ip of the pod. And the jar inside that pod should be up and running at the moment when new backup container trying to connect

Comment: If you just need to know the IP, that should be easily programmatically determined. Read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/), specifically the heading "Using stable network identities"

Comment: Thanks bro for your help. But I have already used stateful sets and determining the pod ip is not the problem that I am facing as I have shown in my code, I can determine it programmatically and already I have used statefulsets. what I am missing is kuberenetes creates pods irrespectively whether the program inside the pod is in the running state or not. I need a mechanism to find that.